# Windows Jenkins slave node unable to pull from git repo after the URL changed

Tags: ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

We had to change our bitbucket URL after which Windows Jenkins slave node is unable to pull the git repo from the new bitbucket URL.  It works fine on Mac /Linux. I have added / accepted the key for the new domain on windows nodes. It works fine when i clone the repo manually on the machine but fails when its done thru jenkins.

More info about the setup:

- Jenkins is setup via ssh key authentication with the Windows slave node.
- ssh agent Jenkins plugin is used for ssh authentication.

```
using credential 046a6520-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdb1139e55
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://git@bitbucket.<new url>.com/<project>/<repo>.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1002)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1244)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1308)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@bitbucket.<new url>.com/<project>/<repo>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: No RSA host key is known for bitbucket.<new url>.com and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2734)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
```

Checks Done :

- Verified that the correct ssh is loaded on the Windows node by using the command  **eval 'ssh-agent -s` ssh-add**
- Verified that the correct user context by running a script in the pipeline
  `script { bat 'echo %USERNAME%' }`
- Restarted Windows node.
- Ran these two commands to remove the configuration for the credential helper in Git 
  `git config --global --unset credential.helper`
  `git config --system --unset credential.helper`
- Reinstalled GIT and added it to the path.

Any help on this is really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked StrictHostKeyChecking in SSH? It might be a factor; if on it will (auto) block hosts if not in known host’s

Comment: I have added the key in known hosts and also turned off StrictHostKeyChecking by mentioning it in a config file in the .ssh folder.

Comment: Any impact? If not; Are you sure the .ssh folder is used by the user running the jenkins agent?  You can also test the connection itself, without  git, by running `ssh -T user@domain.tld` via git bash (or alternative) as the user running the jenkins agent.

Comment: - Setting StrictHostKeyChecking to no, didn't work. <br/>
- Yes , The Jenkins workspace is in the user profile of the Jenkins user and has no access to other files. <br/>
 - When I run ssh -T git@bitbucket.domain.tld on git bash, I get this error 
''' shell request failed on channel 0 '''

Comment: More info will be given if you add -v for extra info in the ssh command (maybe add a port if needed), but is sounds like you can reach the server via ssh. Unfortunately I am out of further ideas; except some you probably already checked 10+ times: Is the key / credential itself okay, A git clone can be executed verbose via -v may give you more data and Is the job / its workspace of influence?